# Глобально скрыть посты для пользователя по условию

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть сайт на WP. И на сайте есть сложные правила для определения - доступен ли пост определенному пользователю.

Есть ли способ глобально, на всех страницах, во всех циклах - убрать эти посты какой-то функцией, чтобы не сломать пагинацию?

Comment: Не надо, пожалуйста, ставить метку РНР. К настройкам программы "вордпресс" она не имеет никакого отношения

Comment: Не надо, пожалуйста, умничать не разбираясь в вопросе - если метка указана - значит имеет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для таких манипуляций существует фильтр [pre_get_posts](https://wp-kama.ru/hook/pre_get_posts). Что там нужно делать, сильно зависит от ваших правил определения доступности поста. Подробнее ответить на этот вопрос не представляется возможным.